# How are bounces / unsubscribed handled?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, unsubscriber, bounce-management

How do unsubscribes and bounces get handled with email sends using data extension?  Are unsubscribers removed from future email sends?  What about hard bounces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your contacts unsubscribe or are in the “bounced” status , this is stored in the all subscribers list. At send time, the OMM will reference the All Subscribers List against your send source ( Data extension or list). Anyone that has unsubscribed or is in the bouncer status will be excluded from the send