# Building an effective Suppression List in Marketing Cloud Enterprise 2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, contactbuilder, unsubscriber, suppressionlist

In our marketing cloud enterprise 2.0 instance, I'm trying to build suppression lists, one for each of our child BUs (brands). We're just standing up our 2.0 instance, so we don't yet have 6 months of data.

My solution is to write a query that pulls the subscriber data view, Unsubscribes per Business Unit data view, and the Bounce data view, joins these up with a SQL query in the Parent BU, then filter to each Business unit utilizing shared data extensions. My suppression list would consist of anyone who is in 'held' status, has had a hard bounce, or who has unsubscribed from that respective BU.

Am I making this more complicated than it has to be? Is there a more effective way, possibly via the Contact Builder in the Parent account? I've looked through it but still pretty green when it comes to Contact Builder functionality.

Comment: Why do you need a suppression list for this? Subscribers in Held status will be automatically suppressed during sends?

Comment: Unsubscribed contacts will also be suppressed - take a look here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229036/how-are-bounces-unsubscribed-handled

Comment: Hi Chorlesbarkley7, how is your subscriber data getting into SFMC? Are signups being directly created, or are you importing/syncing them from an external source (Eg CRM). Are you sending to “Lists” or using Sendable DataExtensions?

Comment: @CameronRobert We're utilizing sendable data extensions from data imported via API from outside CRM. We're wanting to suppress on the Business Unit level, and from what I understand the subscriber status is managed in our parent business unit, so if someone receives a hard bounce or unsubscribe status, they do it for all brands. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Under Business Unit settings, you can select "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only" - which will sort this out for you